# Chunk a large file based on regex (LInux)

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a large text file and I want to chunk it to smaller files based on distinct value of a column , columns are separated by comma (it's a csv file) and there are lots of distinct values :

e.g.

```
1012739937,2006-11-28,d_02245211
1012739937,2006-11-28,d_02238545
1012739937,2006-11-28,d_02236564
1012739937,2006-11-28,d_01918338
1012739937,2006-11-28,d_02148765
1012739937,2006-11-28,d_00868949
1012739937,2006-11-28,d_01908448
1012740478,1998-06-26,d_01913689
1012740478,1998-06-26,i_4869
1012740478,1998-06-26,d_02174766
```

I want to chunk the file into smaller files such that each file contains records belonging to one year (one for records of 2006 , one for records of 1998 , etc)

(here we may have limited number of years , but I want to the same thing with larger number of distinct values of a specific column)

Comment: is `grep ",2006-" ` suitable?

Comment: No , please read the question carefully : (here we may have limited number of years , but I want to the same thing with larger number of distinct values of a specific column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F, '{split($2,d,"-");print > d[1]}' file
```

Explanation:

```
-F,              tells awk that input fields are separated by ','

split($2,d,"-")  splits the second column (the date) by '-'
                 and puts the bits into the array 'd'

print > d[1]     prints the whole input line into a file named after the year
```

Comment: Would you please explain what is 'd' here ?

Comment: So you mean here the array starts from 1 instead of 0 and we don't need to have `;` after `print > d[1]`, right ?

Comment: Yes. `split()` will index the array with 1 as the first index. (like field indexes in awk). As it is the last expression no ; is required at the end

Answer (score 3):

A quick awk solution, if slightly fragile (assumes the second column, if it exists, always starts `yyyy`)

```
awk -F, '$2{print > (substr($2,0,4) ".csv")}' test.in
```

It will split input into files `yyyy.csv`; make sure they don't exist in your current directory or they will be overwritten.

Comment: +1 it's a little bit different but as good as mine (and faster answer) :) .. Maybe even better as you won't need an additional array as me

Answer (score 3):

A different awk take: use a slightly more complicated field separator:

```
awk -F '[,-]' '{print > $2}' file
```

Comment: Cool!!!!!!!! thanks! I didn't know about "complex" field separators. Thats definitely the best answer. The accept should being yours!